# Как расширить свойства класса

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Я переписываю проект с `es5` на `es6` и использую `angular 1.6.1`
Использую классы `es6`. Делаю вот так

```
function getArgs(func) {
    var args = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];

    return args.split(',').map(function(arg) {
        return arg.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//, '').trim();
    }).filter(function(arg) {
        return arg;
    });
}

function extendClassConstructor(object, parameters) {
    let r = [],
        i,
        keys = getArgs(object);

    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        r.push({
            key: keys[i],
            value: parameters[i]
        });
    }

    angular.forEach(r, function (value, key) {
        Object.defineProperty(object, key, {
            value: value
        });
    });
}

export default class DinnerController {
    /** @ngInject */
    constructor(DinnerService, $location, $filter, $scope, DinnerFactory, PaginationFactory, $timeout, CurrencyFactory) {
        extendClassConstructor(this, arguments);

        console.log(this);
    }

}
```

Но вот в чем проблема, если я передаю `this` в `extendClassConstructor`, то будет ошибка
`Cannot read property '1' of null`
на этой строчке
`var args = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];`
А так вообще `this` не расширяется
Что я не так делаю

Я вообще не имею желания так писать

```
this.DinnerService = DinnerService;
this.$location = $location;
this.$filter = $filter;
this.$scope = $scope;
this.DinnerFactory = DinnerFactory;
this.PaginationFactory = PaginationFactory;
this.$timeout = $timeout;
this.CurrencyFactory = CurrencyFactory;
```

Как одно из решений которое я придумал

```
class NgController {
    constructor(child, parameters) {
        let keys = this.getArgs(child);
        let r = [],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            r.push({
                key: keys[i],
                value: parameters[i]
            });
        }

        angular.forEach(r, (obj) => {
            Object.defineProperty(this, obj.key, {
                value: obj.value
            });
        });
    }

    getArgs(func) {
        let args = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];

        return args.split(',').map( (arg) => {
            return arg.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//, '').trim();
        }).filter( (arg) => {
            return arg;
        });
    }
}
```

И в дочернем класс в конструкторе делаем так

```
class DinnerController extends NgController

super(DinnerController, arguments);
```

Но опять же, можно ли все таки расширить прототип классов и просто потом в конструкторе вызывать `this.extendPropeties(arguments)`
Типа так можно ?

Comment: проблема в том, что `this` у тебя в конструкторе - это **не** функция, это конструируемый объект, поэтому `func.toString().match(` вернет `null`

Comment: значит пока лучший выход это как я предложил ?

Comment: нет. На самом деле вообще непонятно что ты делаешь. По сути ты мог  просто передавать конструктор вместо объекта. либо как в твоем решении - сам класс. Кроме этого можно было воспользоваться свойством $inject.

Comment: _Я вообще не имею желания так писать_ - в таком случае стоит посмотреть в сторону typescript, там есть возможность [быстрого создания свойств](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties)